Check all boxes in slicers
I'm trying to programmatically check all boxes in a Google Sheet's sheet using Apps Script.
I think there is code somewhere whether it's from the source or in some other code else that edits the slicers to show (e.g.) 1 of 4 checkboxes, but I was unable to find it or it may not be visible to me.
Specifically, I'm trying to get the Slicers and select all checkboxes in said slicers, then iterate to the next slicer until there are no more.
Along with extensively looking through Google documentation and forums, I have yet to find a solution.
Here are just a few of the .gs code I have tried:
function selectAllSlicers() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var slicers = spreadsheet.getSlicers();

  slicers.forEach(function(slicer) {
    var items = slicer.getRange().getValues();
    slicer.setRangeValues(items);
  });
}

//This works in retrieving the names of the Slicers.

// -

function checkAllSlicers() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var slicers = spreadsheet.getSlicers();

  slicers.forEach(function(slicer) {
    var range = slicer.getRange();

    var checkboxes = range.getDataValidations();

    checkboxes.forEach(function(row, rowIndex) {
      row.forEach(function(cell, colIndex) {
        if (cell == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
          range.getCell(rowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1).setValue(true);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

// No visible change on the sheet.

//--

function checkSlicersOnSheet1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<SPREADSHEET_ID>/edit');

  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  const slicers = sheet.getSlicers();

  for (const slicer of slicers) {
    const slicerValues = slicer.getRange().getSlicerValues();
    if (slicerValues) {
      for (const value of slicerValues) {
        slicer.setIsItemChecked(value, true);
      }
    }
  }
}

//Changes all cells to "TRUE".


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand Specifically, I'm trying to get the Slicers and select all checkboxes in said slicers, then iterate to the next slicer until there are no more.. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The comments in the code are misplaced, and you might be confusing concepts, like the in-cell checkboxes with the slicers options. Please bear in mind that questions on this site should be specific; considering this, please make the question more focused, i.e., include only one function, but ensure that this function is a [mcve]. This implies including sample data and showing the options in the slicer.

@Wicket I was trying to explain the issue and what I wanted to happen, as well as showing what code I had tried. I did my best to be as specific as possible.

@Tanaike. In Google Sheets, if you go to Data > Add a slicer. I want to programatically check/select all checkboxes in these Slicers, but in every Slicer on the sheet until there are no more Slicers left.

This is what I wanted and this shows "All" or has all checkboxes ticked in all Slicers:
function selectAllFiltersInSlicers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Set the working sheet to the Sheet1 sheet
  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers(); // Gets slicers in sheet (Slicers are the black filters at the top of the sheet)
  
  for (var i = 0; i < slicers.length; i++) { // Iterates through each slicer in forward order
    var slicer = slicers[i];
    var column = slicer.getColumnPosition(); // Gets the column the slicer is filtering
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                                  .setHiddenValues([]) // This sets empty array or no hidden values. So all filters including blanks will show.
                                  .build(); 
    slicer.setColumnFilterCriteria(column, criteria); // Resets the column position and adds criteria.
  }
}


Select the range of cells where the check boxes are in one contiguous range and then run  this function.
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      let r = sh.getRange(row + i, col + j).getDataValidation();
      if (r && r.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
        Logger.log(sh.getRange(row + i, col + j).getA1Notation())
        sh.getRange(row + i, col + j).check();
      }
    })
  });
}

This version will toggle them:
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      let r = sh.getRange(row + i, col + j).getDataValidation();
      if (r && r.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
        Logger.log(sh.getRange(row + i, col + j).getA1Notation())
        let r = sh.getRange(row + i, col + j);
        if(r.isChecked()) {
          r.uncheck();
        } else {
          r.check();
        }
      }
    })
  });
}

